# Iteraction for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, recursion

A function f is deﬁned by the rule that

[image]

Write a function *f(n)* that computes `f` by an iterative process

I wrote this. and still not getting it right. Please advise how to fix it.

```
def f(n):
    if (n<3):
        return n
    else:
        for x in range (n):
            a = f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3)
            return (a)
```

Comment: take out remove your for loop, x is not used

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? The `for x in range` isn't doing anything; you can remove that line. But what's wrong with the answers the function is giving you?

Comment: @TheDrooper: I think it is bloated: you will create an entire call tree with loads of duplicated work. The time complexity of this is exponential (also without the `for`), whereas an iterative is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use a memory cache:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 3:
        return n
    a,b,c = 0,1,2
    for i in range(n-2):
        a,b,c = b,c,c+2*b+3*a
    return c
```

In this function we use `a` to denote *f(n-3)*, `b` to denote *f(n-2)* and `c` for *f(n-1)*, at each iterative step, we calculate *f(n)* and thus we shift: `a` becomes `b`, `b` becomes `c` and `c` obtains the new value. We do this until we have reached the requested `n`.

So initially we will calculate *f(3)*. In that case, `a` is *f(0)=0*, `b` is *f(1)=1*, and `c` is *f(2)=2*. Now after that iteration, `a` takes *f(1)=1*, `b` takes *f(2)=2*, and `c` takes *f(3)=f(2)+2×f(1)+3×f(0)=5*, and you keep doing that until `c` has the right `n`.

This will work faster since in the recursive variant, you call for `f(n-2)` and `f(n-1)`, but `f(n-1)` will on his way call for `f(n-2)` thus introducing duplicated work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to return first `n` elements, you can use simple dynamic programming with memoization with `O(n)` space and time:

```
def F(n):
    f = [0]*n
    f[:4] = range(4)  
    for i in range(4, n):
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2] + f[i-3]
    return f    

print F(20) 
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125, 230, 423, 778, 1431, 2632, 4841, 8904, 16377, 30122, 55403]
```